# Update of a table in the MySQL linked server fails with a syntax error after SQL Server security update

Tags: sql-server, mysql

I have a linked server that has been running this update for several years.  It is on a SQL 2012 and 2012 R2 OS.  We took a Microsoft security update this weekend and now this query is failing.  I have included the error message.  I can go to MYSQL Workbench with the same userid and make the update and the syntac is very similar. I am using MYSQL ODBC 8.0.26 which is the latest.  I have install this ODBC driver on my personal PC and get the same results.

```
UPDATE ivr
SET Ivr.exported = '2021-07-26 18:25:12.0000000'
FROM   OPENQUERY(MYSQLprd, 'SELECT id, exported FROM us_apikcmorg.ivr_request') as ivr
where IVR.id = '0ac65de5-ed48-11eb-b181-0e7426bee2cd'
```

Here is the error:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQLprd" returned message "[MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver][mysqld-5.7.33-log]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`ivr_request` SET `exported`=? WHERE `id`=? AND `exported` IS NULL' at line 1".
>
> Msg 7343, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
>
> The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQLprd" could not UPDATE table "[MSDASQL]".

Comment: what you seei the message that the prepared statements wasn't filled with data, so you should provide us with a cleare picture how you build the update comand, as it has nothing to do with odbc or mysql

Comment: I am running this command from SSMS just as it is.  This command was pulled from an SSIS package that had been working until we took a Microsoft update on Saturday.

Comment: we turned on logging on the MYSQL database and the update statement never gets there.  So you are correct.  here is the statement.  It is put is a SQL Task Editor that points to a LinkedServer that uses a MYSQL ODBC drive( 8.0.26).

Comment: UPDATE ivr 
SET    ivr.exported = Pivr.WebSynced 
FROM   OPENQUERY(MYSQLTST, 'SELECT id, exported FROM us_apikcmorg.ivr_request') as ivr 
       INNER JOIN [KCM].[PlumIVR] Pivr ON Pivr.id = ivr.id